# Popular AI plugin?

Tags: unity, ai, plugin

Need help to list popular AI unity plugins. 
Some people prefer one over other based on features and ease of use.

1. ?
2. ?
   n. Rain AI 
   ...

Comment: Welcome to gamedev, sadly tool recomendations are off-topic, that is just the way it is. Take a minute to take our [tour](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tour) and see what is [on-topic](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Also, you'd need to be a lot more specific than "AI". Or do you really want to compare the Fritz Chess AI with Rain AI?

Comment: Behavior designer is my absolute favorite.